# How to set schemaLocation for XML file generated using XMLBeans in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I generated an XML file using XMLBeans in Java. The result is something like this:

```
<ipdr:IPDRDoc IPDRRecorderInfo="192.168.95.82" xmlns:ipdr="uri://www.ipdr.org/namespaces/ipdr" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:DOCSIS-QOS="uri://www.cablelabs.com/namespaces/DOCSIS/3.0/xsd/ipdr/DOCSIS-QOS">

    <ipdr:IPDR xsi:type="doc:SAMIS-TYPE-1" xmlns:doc="uri://www.cablelabs.com/namespaces/DOCSIS/3.0/xsd/ipdr/DOCSIS-SAMIS-TYPE-1">   
    <DOCSIS-QOS:ServiceTimeCreated>1474597117000</DOCSIS-QOS:ServiceTimeCreated>
    <DOCSIS-QOS:ServiceTimeActive>100</DOCSIS-QOS:ServiceTimeActive>
    </ipdr:IPDR>  

</ipdr:IPDRDoc>
```

Now I want to move definition of namespace `xmlns:doc="uri://www.cablelabs.com/namespaces/DOCSIS/3.0/xsd/ipdr/DOCSIS-SAMIS-TYPE-1"` in element `<ipdr:IPDR>` into the root node `<ipdr:IPDRDoc>`. Afterwards the XML file should look like:

```
<ipdr:IPDRDoc IPDRRecorderInfo="192.168.95.82" xmlns:ipdr="uri://www.ipdr.org/namespaces/ipdr" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:DOCSIS-QOS="uri://www.cablelabs.com/namespaces/DOCSIS/3.0/xsd/ipdr/DOCSIS-QOS" xsi:schemaLocation="uri://www.cablelabs.com/namespaces/DOCSIS/3.0/xsd/ipdr/DOCSIS-SAMIS-TYPE-1
                    DOCSIS-SAMIS-TYPE-1_3.5.1-A.1.xsd">

    <ipdr:IPDR xsi:type="doc:SAMIS-TYPE-1">   
    <DOCSIS-QOS:ServiceTimeCreated>1474597117000</DOCSIS-QOS:ServiceTimeCreated>
    <DOCSIS-QOS:ServiceTimeActive>100</DOCSIS-QOS:ServiceTimeActive>
    </ipdr:IPDR>  

</ipdr:IPDRDoc>
```

How can I do it? I tried to use `xmlOption.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(suggestedPrefixes);` but without success.
Is there any way to do that?